# Programmatically add people to Circle using Google Plus Domain API?

Tags: php, api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-plus-domains

I try to adding people to circle by this code:

```
$this->google = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains($this->client);

......

$this->google->circles->addPeople(
    $circleId, ['userId' => $userId]
);
```

I get the error:

```
Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/circles/{Circle_ID}/people?userId={USER_ID}:

(403) The operation is not allowed because the requested people are not part of the domain
```

I see in Google Plus Domain document, but It have not php example (just java and ruby): https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/adding

Comment: Are both users from the same [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) account?

Comment: No. 2 different accounts. 1 google app account and 1 regular account.

Comment: The Domains API only works with Google Apps users that are part of the same domain.

Comment: Thank you!!! So how can I add a people into a circle or list all people in a circle (Regular account, not Google Apps users).